# UWP remove item in listview by clicking a button in listview

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to remove an item from the listview when I click a button in the listview row. The listview row is composed by a textbox and a button: I need to get the name of the text in the textbox becouse it is used in xml file, which populate the listview itself.

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="listView_names" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="169" Margin="52,221,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="336" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                <Button x:Name="removeBtn" Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Background="#FF888888" Foreground="#FF292C33"  Click="remove_Click"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image: listview with buttons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind the Tag of the Button e.g. `Tag="{Binding Name}"` then when you get the object sender you can cast that back to a Button e.g. `Button button = (Button)sender;` in the `remove_Click` Method then read the name from the Tag property of that

Comment: This works, but probably isn't the best solution though.

Comment: Indeed, it was something I thought of as soon as I saw the question but if there's a better way suggested then feel free to change the accepted answer - sometimes the first idea isn't the best one - I'm happy to admit that!

Comment: With my code it works... I don't know if exists something better, any suggestions @JustinXL?

Comment: @JustinXL I don't know why but yesterday stackoverflow doesn't shows your answer!

Comment: If Justin XL's answer works better then feel free to change the accepted answer to their's